# How to remove a certain print to file feature of Devexpress document Viewer

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

hi im just wondering when i tried to print the report on devexpress document viewer i found a weird feature that i donw really need in terms of functionality and i want to remove it is there a way to remove it??.. this is the feature that i want to remove kindly see image for reference

[image]

Is there a way to remove it? i spend hours looking for solution for this but i cant find it i just thought that you guys could possibly help me thank in advance

Comment: Do you not need that in case a user 'prints' to pdf/etc?

Comment: i dont really need it though is there a way to get rid of that?

Comment: you would have to stop the user from selecting 'PDF'/'XML' etc. To be honest, if this is you're biggest concern, then you're doing pretty damn ok!

Comment: i see.. but my main concern is that is there a way to remove it?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the [DefaultPrintDialogRunner](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsPreviewDefaultPrintDialogRunnertopic), returned by the `PrintDialogRunner.Instance` property, with a customized version of the [SystemPrintDialogRunner](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsPreviewSystemPrintDialogRunnertopic) or the [DefaultPrintDialogRunner](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsPreviewDefaultPrintDialogRunnertopic)  class.

Here is the way to replace the default PrintDialogRunner:

```
using DevExpress.XtraEditors.Preview;
// ...
static void Main(string[] args) {
    PrintDialogRunner.Instance = new SystemPrintDialogRunner(); // !!!
    // ...
}
```

The code above will result that the PrintTool.PrintDialog method will invoke the standard system Print dialog:
[image]

Then you should create your own version of PrintDialogRunner that invokes the [PrintDialogRunner.Run](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsPreviewPrintDialogRunner_Runtopic) method with the the specific flags and use this class in the approach mentioned above:

```
class CustomPrintDialogRunner : DefaultPrintDialogRunner {
    public override DialogResult Run(PrintDocument document, UserLookAndFeel lookAndFeel, 
        IWin32Window owner, PrintDialogAllowFlags flags) {
        // Disable the print-to-file option.
        flags &= ~PrintDialogAllowFlags.AllowPrintToFile;
        return base.Run(document, lookAndFeel, owner, flags);
    }
}
//...
PrintDialogRunner.Instance = new CustomPrintDialogRunner ();
```

Comment: how would i insert the document there to be printed?

Comment: Thank you able to run this smoothly